# почему E_ACCESSDENIED от VBoxManage?

Tags: android, ubuntu, virtualbox, genymotion

не работает genymotion

выбираю virtual device из списка, долго висит экран эмулятора, а потом окно исчезает без сообщений

в логе такая запись:

```
Jul 20 11:46:42 [Genymotion] [debug] [VBox] VM engine version: "5.0.40_Ubuntur115130"
Jul 20 11:46:42 [Genymotion] [debug] VMX/SVM CPU availability: true
Jul 20 11:46:42 [Genymotion] [debug] VM engine version: "5.0.40_Ubuntur115130"
Jul 20 11:46:42 [Genymotion] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("list", "vms")
Jul 20 11:46:42 [Genymotion] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
Jul 20 11:46:42 [Genymotion] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "enumerate", "4a9cc299-cc77-4b58-8934-4877293a450c")
Jul 20 11:46:42 [Genymotion] [critical] [VBox] Return code: 1
Jul 20 11:46:42 [Genymotion] [critical] [VBox] Output command: "VBoxManage: error: The object functionality is limited
VBoxManage: error: Details: code E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "LockMachine(a->session, LockType_Shared)" at line 253 of file VBoxManageGuestProp.cpp"
Jul 20 11:46:42 [Genymotion] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "enumerate", "968add45-3d41-444a-ae0f-b48a59ef89e3")
Jul 20 11:46:42 [Genymotion] [critical] [VBox] Return code: 1
Jul 20 11:46:42 [Genymotion] [critical] [VBox] Output command: "VBoxManage: error: The object functionality is limited
VBoxManage: error: Details: code E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "LockMachine(a->session, LockType_Shared)" at line 253 of file VBoxManageGuestProp.cpp"
Jul 20 11:46:42 [Genymotion] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "enumerate", "2e84bc6c-c1d7-44e9-98f9-950b783f8cd9")
Jul 20 11:46:42 [Genymotion] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
```

как исправить ошибку?

Answer (score 1):

оказалось проблема в драйверах видеокарты